# Can I, when writing a book, make use of a physical model made up by someone else?

Tags: writing

Currently, I'm writing a book about everything from A to Z [physics, the science of the brain, AI, many more scientific topics, the "philosophy" (the workings) of the sciences, economy, the destruction of Nature and can she still be saved for future generations, the place of the sciences in society, etc.].

I'm a big fan of a certain physical model: The [Rishon model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishon_model), invented by Haïm Harari. Can I use his theory without further consequences? Or is it good propaganda for his theory?

Comment: And you may well find that the amount of references you need to use matches or even exceeds the text you write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone can use anyone else’s published theory as long as they cite their sources and don’t try to falsely claim ownership of the ideas of others. So yes, if you present it honestly as Harari’s theory then of course you can use it in your book.